# Parameterize the following line integral

Tags: solution-verification, line-integrals

$$\int _{\gamma }xydx\:+zdy\:-yzdz\:$$ where$$\:\gamma \::\:x^2+y^2=4\: \text{and}\:z=x^2+y^2$$

I assumed $$x\left(t\right)=2\cos t\:,\:y\left(t\right)=2\sin t,\:z\left(t\right)=4$$

Is it correct?

Comment: Indeed, your $x(t),y(t),z(t)$ do give $z(t) = x(t)^2 + y(t)^2 = 4$.. But "correct" probably also depends on the direction you want to traverse $\gamma$ (clockwise versus counterclockwise). You'll want to double check that your param's given the right orientation.

Comment: Thanks!Also the domain for t is [0, 2\pi ] right?

Comment: Yes parametrization is correct. You should also write $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$ if anticlockwise direction.

Comment: Thanks! Also is there another representation graphic I can do besides the circle? I heard you could do a sphere here from a friend but I have no idea what he meant.

Comment: You should tag user (if your question is to a specific user) when you write otherwise many times we do not get notification for your comment. As you are OP, you get notification regardless. To your question, there is no other representation of the curve. It is a circle at $z = 4$. It is intersection curve of two surfaces - $x^2+y^2 = 4$ and $z = x^2+y^2$. The first one is a cylinder and the second is a paraboloid.

Comment: I see, thanks again!